# So Many Gridlines.... Can you reach your destination?

Tags: combinatorics

**Question :** [SOURCE](https://brilliant.org/problems/can-you-reach-your-destination/)

You are at the bottom left square of a $7 × 9$ grid. In each turn, you can either move a **square up, a square down or a square right.** You cannot go back to the square you came from. You have to reach to the top right square. In how many ways can you do so?

If your answer can be written as $\displaystyle  a^b$ enter your answer as $a + b$.

[image]

**My strategy:**

I thought that we have to move exactly $7 \ units$ horizontally and have to move alteast $9 \ units $ and at max $9 \times 8 \ units $ vertically. Then I calculated

$$\displaystyle \sum_{k=9}^{72} { {n+7} \choose 7} = { 80 \choose 8 } - { 16 \choose 8} $$ But it is definitely not of the form $\displaystyle  a^b$.

**I would appreciate a hint, not a solution.**

Comment: I have added source..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: You are entirely free to choose at which height you make each of your 9 right-wards moves.

Comment: Please elaborate.

Comment: @NikolaAlfredi "I would appreciate a hint, not a solution." I can't elaborate much more without giving it away entirely.

Comment: Ok, no problem... I will go with that.

Comment: I got the answer. $7^9$ ?

Comment: @NikolaAlfredi That's the one. You will, of course, have to make sure that a choice of 9 heights is exactly the same as a valid choice of path, so that you neither overcount nor miss anything.

Comment: Thank you for the advice .... I am greateful to you..

Comment: What would happen if we altered this a little bit... i.e we can move UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT ?

Comment: @NikolaAlfredi Then I could travel in a circuit infinitely. There would be an infinite number of paths

Comment: Yes, that is what I thought....

Comment: @NikolaAlfredi And even with the restriction that we cannot visit the same cell twice, it becomes _really_ complicated trying to calculate the number of paths.

Comment: Yes, I tried that... it was very complicated.

Comment: @NikolaAlfredi For grids of varying sizes, the number of paths is given by [this sequence](http://oeis.org/A064298). There isn't much information there, which to me means there isn't much known.

Comment: Thank you for sharing it with me.

Answer (score 1):

You have $7$ steps up, and $9$ steps right.

$1$ right step is already taken

Now since you can also move down, number of steps towards right are the limiting factor.

There are $8$ rightward steps.

These $8$ steps can be made at any of the

So there are a total of $7^8$ ways this can be done.

Comment: This might work when we are not allowed to **move down**. When we move either forwards or upwards then we might get : $\displaystyle \binom {16}{7} $.

Comment: But we are already on the bottom left tile, so doesnt this make the total step$=14$

Comment: Yes, you are right, when we talk about *squares*. I was taking about lines..

Comment: This solution is also true.